# file_get_contents jpg corrupt download

Tags: php, image, jpeg, file-get-contents

I am downloading this photo using function: file_get_contents(), and it seems to be corrupted. But original photo looks fine.

Original photo:
[original photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwMiA.jpg)

Downloaded photo:
[Download photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY4Cz.jpg)

Code:

```
$current = file_get_contents($image);
$name = '/tmp/img/' . uniqid().".jpg";
file_put_contents($name, $current);
$tmpImages[] = $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function savephoto($urlpath,$savepath)
{ //Download images from url
    $in =    fopen($urlpath, "rb");
    $out =   fopen($savepath, "wb");
    while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
    {
        fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}

savephoto('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwMiA.jpg','newname.jpg');
```

Comment: Still not working, getting more random corrupted images

Comment: its working on my localhost with same image. i think your host or provider get error. try it on localhost or other host.

Comment: maybe my uploaded image was somehow compressed by stackoverflow?

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow has limit for download size. Try it on localhost

Comment: I tried it on localhost with GD, I tried it on remote server with imagick, still the same :/

Comment: if you have enother host provider try at there. if still same you can use curl download.

Comment: So i didn't find any problem solve, I used simple cURL to download good quality pictures.