# php ensure file_get_contents images not corrput

Tags: php

I have a php script to use file_get_contents to download remote images to server, but sometime it is corrupted

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
list($width,$height) = getimagesizefromstring( $contents );

if($width <= 300 ){
    $contents = base64_decode('isdfafasfgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    $downloadlog->log( "ignore file width below 300 : " . $url );
}

$aws->writeToAWS( $target_path , $contents );
$contents = null;
```

Are there any ways to ensure the images are downloaded correctly without any corruption or a way to validate the images against remote url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate using [getimagesize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

> Note:
>   Some formats may contain no image or may contain multiple images. In these cases, getimagesize() might not be able to properly determine the image size. getimagesize() will return zero for width and height in these cases.
>
> On failure, FALSE is returned.

---

edited:

for example

```
<?php
$array = getimagesize('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22492671/not_an_image.jpg');
if( $array ){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo 'image broken';
}
?>
```

`getimagesize()` return false when image is broken.

Comment: How can i test the images are corrupted using getimagesize, are there any script to test?

Comment: i've test, still not working :( this case is similar to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030224/file-get-contents-jpg-corrupt-download

Comment: the corrupted image will never return false from getimagesize

Comment: @hkguile in that case, getimagesize() should return an array, right? what is in the array ?

Comment: i had tried to use getimagesize($corrupt_url) and getimagesize($ok_url) , it returns an array with same information.

Comment: @hkguile have you checked their width & height in the array? is it 0? can i have the links for `$corrupt_url` and `$ok_url` ?

Comment: the width & height are the same.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pwMiA.jpg http://i.stack.imgur.com/fY4Cz.jpg , the case are same, but the background are white

Comment: @hkguile theoretically, this image aren't broken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995096/php-determine-visually-corrupted-images-yet-valid-downloaded-via-curl-with-gd
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php

Comment: @hkguile I haven't used imagick before. I am unable to help you in this case. Sorry

Comment: it seems work
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php (the comment solution of the page)